# Ubuntu 23.04: Weird white windows on some applications (GTK4)

Tags: themes, gtk, gtk4

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 and have noticed that some applications are displaying a white border instead of applying the system theme. I suspect this may be related to the update to GTK4.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

**Edit:** It happens only Wayland. In x.org the window frames are black as the system theme.
If found out, that all applications affected are QT-based for example Master PDF Editor, Recoll and Qutebrowser.

Also I noticed that the mouse cursor appears bigger in QT-based applications.

[image]

Comment: "some applications". This information is not very specific, so not quite helpfull. It is rather difficult to reproduce your issue, leave anone debug it, with this information.

Comment: What display server, X.org or Wayland? Do both do the same?

Comment: Thanks for you comments, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I am also getting same. how did you solved this @Philipp